# How to populate an XSL variable with a nested value from the XML?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm using XSL 1.0 and trying to reach deep into a series of XML nodes to retrieve a value. Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mpcconfiguration>
   <lineitem id="0" seriesid="series1" modelid="model1">
      <seriesdesc>Series #1</seriesdesc>
      <modeldesc>Model #1</modeldesc>
      <category id="Mstr_Information">
         <option id="Mstr_Information">
            <unitprice>0</unitprice>
            <property id="ExtPrice">0</property>
            <property id="Mstr_ModelSortOrder">3</property>
         </option>
      </category>
   </lineitem>
   <lineitem id="1" seriesid="series2" modelid="model2">
      <seriesdesc>Series #2</seriesdesc>
      <modeldesc>Model #2</modeldesc>
      <category id="Mstr_Information">
         <option id="Mstr_Information">
            <description>descr1</description>
            <unitprice>0</unitprice>
            <property id="ExtPrice">0</property>
            <property id="Mstr_ModelSortOrder">1</property>
         </option>
      </category>
   </lineitem>
   <lineitem id="2" seriesid="series3" modelid="model3">
      <seriesdesc>Series #3</seriesdesc>
      <modeldesc>Model #3</modeldesc>
      <category id="Mstr_Information">
         <option id="Mstr_Information">
            <description>descr1</description>
            <unitprice>0</unitprice>
            <property id="ExtPrice">0</property>
            <property id="Mstr_ModelSortOrder">2</property>
         </option>
      </category>
   </lineitem>
</mpcconfiguration>
```

Here's the selector to the value within each `<lineitem>` that I'm trying to get:

```
category[@id='Mstr_Information']/option[@id='Mstr_Information']/property[@id='Mstr_ModelSortOrder']
```

I know the above selector is correct because I'm using it successfully for sort purposes near the top of the XSL. (Thank you Tomalak!)

I'm trying to extract that into a variable thusly:

```
<xsl:variable name="modelSortOrder">
    <xsl:value-of select="category[@id='Mstr_Information']/option[@id='Mstr_Information']/property[@id='Mstr_ModelSortOrder']"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

...and then use it later on like this:

```
<span style="width: 50px">
   <b>Model Sort Order: </b>
</span>
<xsl:value-of select="$modelSortOrder" />
```

Fail: I end up with an empty string for `$modelSortOrder`

Here is a stripped down (and hopefully runnable) version of my current XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
   
   <xsl:template match="mpcconfiguration">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
         <xsl:apply-templates select="lineitem">
            <xsl:sort select="category[@id='Mstr_Information']/option[@id='Mstr_Information']/property[@id='Mstr_ModelSortOrder']" data-type="number" />
         </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   
   <xsl:template match="lineitem">
      <xsl:variable name="lineItemId">
         <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="seriesId">
         <xsl:value-of select="@seriesid"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="modelId">
         <xsl:value-of select="@modelid"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      
      <xsl:variable name="modelSortOrder">
         <xsl:value-of select="category[@id='Mstr_Information']/option[@id='Mstr_Information']/property[@id='Mstr_ModelSortOrder']"/>
      </xsl:variable>

      <div class="xRgn">
         <table class="xInner">
            <tr>
               <td class="col">
                  <xsl:element name="div">
                     <div style="float:left; margin:3px">
                        
                      <span style="width: 50px">
                         <b>Series: </b>
                      </span>
                      <xsl:choose>
                         <xsl:when test="not(seriesdesc)">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@seriesid" />
                         </xsl:when>
                         <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="seriesdesc" />
                         </xsl:otherwise>
                      </xsl:choose>
                      <br />
                      <span style="width: 50px">
                         <b>Model: </b>
                      </span>
                      <xsl:choose>
                         <xsl:when test="not(modeldesc)">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@modelid" />
                         </xsl:when>
                         <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="modeldesc" />
                         </xsl:otherwise>
                      </xsl:choose>
                      <br />
                      <span style="width: 50px">
                         <b>Model Sort Order: </b>
                      </span>
                      <xsl:value-of select="$modelSortOrder" />
                      <br />
                      
                     </div>
                  </xsl:element>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </div>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above runs fine (except for the empty variable) in my .NET environment, but hopefully it will run for you too, in whatever tool you're using. My XSLT output correctly sorts, and correctly loops over the `<lineitem>` sections, and correctly emits HTML for each of those sections.

Comment: Well, I cannot confirm this behavior. The value is output as expected - checked it with Saxon (and also `xsltproc`, although it's an XSLT-1.0 processor). In both cases, it worked. Last (relevant) line of output is `<span style="width: 50px">
                                <b>Model Sort Order: </b>
                            </span>
                            3<br/>`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem either. I would suggest you do not tag your stylesheet as `version="2.0"` if it's intended to run in XSLT 1.0, and also that you use `<xsl:variable name="modelSortOrder" select="category[@id='Mstr_Information']/option[@id='Mstr_Information']/property[@id='Mstr_ModelSortOrder']"/>` instead of what you have - but neither is relevant to the problem you report.

Comment: Frick. I changed the 2.0 to 1.0 - sorry did not even notice that.

Comment: I made the suggested changes (1.0 and variable) and it's all working now in my .NET. Thanks so much guys.